# Want to set same size in different font system style for flutter

Tags: flutter, fonts, font-size

I want to set same size for different font system in flutter. How to set with this? With the Unicode system all the font is fine in app but with other system font (Example, wrong font format from backend.) the font size is too big that set in code and app UI alignment is so ugly. How to do that problem?

```
Container(
            width: ScreenSizeConfig.screenWidth / 1.115,
            child: Text(
              nameFromAPI,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: kTitleTextStyle(
                size: 24,
              ).copyWith(
                wordSpacing: 3,
              ),
            ),
```

This photo is with the correct unicode font.[image]

........

In this photo, with wrong format fonts, UI misalign badly.[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Container(
            width: ScreenSizeConfig.screenWidth / 1.115,
            height: 35,
            child: Center(
              child: FittedBox(
                child: Text(
                  agentName,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  style: kTitleTextStyle(
                    size: 24,
                  ).copyWith(
                    wordSpacing: 3,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Giving `Height` to the `Container` solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap text widget to Fitted box to fit in fix size

```
FittedBox(
   child: Text(
      "Some Text Here. More. More. More. More. More. More. More. More. ",
       maxLines: 1)
)
```

Comment: Or you can wrap text in container or sizedbox and give height or you can give direlty height to text widget.

Comment: Yes.... may be using```container``` or ```SizedBox``` with height will be right answer. ```FittedBox``` not useful. I will test again with height

Comment: okay let me know if any of not works

Comment: I answer the problem. Thanks for advice.